# How to calculate the age of a person in a string field with multiple date formats?

Tags: date

Bumped into a post of 9gag where someone made some fun of someone's coding (or just a joke of a coder). My question is more of a serious note, hypothetical speaking under set conditions, could that be one of the better solutions on hand (the principal)?

[Link to the comment of whom posted the picture below](https://9gag.com/gag/ap9DZ2D?utm_source=copy_link&utm_medium=comment_share#cs_comment_id=c_168116209378054478)

[image]

If the set context of this problem is that the dates are stored in a string field where the date format could be like YYYY-MM-DD, but also YYYY-DD-MM, DD-MM-YYYY, or MM-DD-YYYY, what would be the best approach be for this context to calculate someone's age?

I don't have access to an SQL server where I would be able to mess about with this, thus I can't test certain things, but someone proposes that a simple "DateDiff" should work. Wouldn't that only work under the condition the field is an integer and the field is a single format?

My proposal to the question would be slightly tweaked, by stating

```
when $(date_of_brith) like '%1939%' then extract ( year from sysdate ) - 1939
```

**How would you approach a challenge where multiple date formats reside in a single text field?**

> *Wouldn't be the first time I would see something similar. I've seen scenarios where Business decides upon a different format, which is subsequently adjusted for the entry field. However, Business, maintaining the budget and in absence of a data governance structure, decides that the past can remain the past and doesn't need to be modified to the requested new format. Thereby, 2 formats reside in one field. The implication was as well that on older records that the different formats were both visible via the API as UI, as you would expect. They concluded it would have no impact because my BI tool with my modeling would be able to compensate for it, and thus would have no significant impact.*

Answer (score 2):

> the date format could be like YYYY-MM-DD, but also YYYY-DD-MM, DD-MM-YYYY, or MM-DD-YYYY, what would be the best approach be for this context to calculate someone's age?

### Not possible.

Without other supplemental information, it's not *completely* possible to discern the correct date between the formats of `DD-MM-YYYY` and `MM-DD-YYYY`, or between the formats of `YYYY-MM-DD` and `YYYY-DD-MM`.

Example dates that would be impossible to discern are `01-02-2023`, `02-01-2023`, and pretty much any date whose day of the month is `12` or less. Is the first example date `January 2nd` or `February 1st`?...same question for the second example date? Being able to deterministically parse the day and month is important for getting the age accurately relative to the current date of the year. The example code from 9gag technically is incorrect and has a bug, because of this.

If it was guaranteed that there were no conflicting date formats stored in the field, then it would be possible to properly parse the date values.

Even more correct, from a database perspective, would be to use a proper date data type to actually store the data. It's *denormalized* to store it as a string, making it error prone and inefficient.

---

> I don't have access to an SQL server where I would be able to mess about with this...

Sidenote, [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk) is a great website for writing and testing SQL code online, for free, with the option of selecting one of the many mainstream database systems to use.

Comment: That's the limitation as I had in mind. The accuracy of the age would have the limitation of being potentially 365 too soon. Finetuning it could reduce the risk of a mistake by considering that the date could be matched on days where the day is above 12, making 221 days accurate and have it "only" potentially 349 days too soon. 
My only concern would be like how you would approach it if you're forced to make it work? How would you make sure that next year, next year's age would be possible? Would you pre-code the next 100 years? Like:

like %2052% then extract ( year from sysdate ) - 2052

Comment: @DouwevanderMeer I'd probably use some form of pattern matching or RegEx to parse out the year, so no hard-coding is needed. This is really more of a StackOverflow question at that point though.